# Correct use of Elvis operator in Angular2 for Dart component's view

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I see in Angular2 Dart [Angular for Dart Cheat Sheet (v2.0.0-beta.2)](https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html) that the Elvis operator is supported.

I am trying to use it in an a components view but it seems that it is not allowed here.

Given

#### .html

```
  <div
    <label
        for = "first">First<span class = "require">*</span></label>
    <input
        type = "text"
        [(ngModel)] = "name?.first"
        id = "first">
```

#### .dart

```
...
Name name = new Name();
...
```

Running the application gives the following error:

#### error trace

```
Transform TemplateCompiler on 
epimss_ng2_reg|lib/components/name_component.ng_meta.json threw error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 13 in [name?.first=$event] in NameComponent@39:12 ("
        <input
            type = "text"
            [ERROR ->][(ngModel)] = "name?.first"
            #firstCtrl = "ngForm"
            [ngFormControl] = "nameForm"): NameComponent@39:12
```

What circumstance can I use the operator in a component's view?

Cheers

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As the error message says it can't be used for assignment. Where should the value be assigned to when `name` is null? 
If you split the short form to the more explicit one

```ts
[ngModel]="name?.first" (ngModelChange)="name.first=$event"
```

then you can use the elvis operator.

Comment: How can I clear the value from the text which I typed. I did the same think but when I call a clear function which just the text box , but it is not clearing the text box in which I have used this operator.

Comment: Bot sure what you mean. What abour `this.name = '';`

Comment: What should be the splitting for `[(ngModel)]=x?.y?.z?.k` ? Considering `x===null`

Comment: `[ngModel]="x?.y?.z?.k" (ngModelChange)="x?.y?.z && x.y.z.k = $event"`

Comment: because in the same form sometimes if the elvil operator works and sometimes not?

Comment: I'm sure it always works. What do you mean with "not work" exactly anyway?

Answer (score 9):

In the case that name is null you can also do this

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="name" [(ngModel)]="name.first">
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `component.ts` class and initialize the model's properties to `""` or whatever the appropriate default value should be.

A good place would be `ngOnInit()` method.

This helped me on Angular 5.

Answer (score -1):

You can use *ngIf, but sometimes it fails.

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="name" [(ngModel)]="name.first">
```

Bind the data of the textarea with [value] or [ngModel]:
For input:

```
<input type="text" (change)="dosomething($event.target.value)" [value]="!noHero ? (hero?.name) : ''">
<input type="text" (change)="dosomething($event.target.value)" [ngModel]="!noHero ? (hero?.name) : ''">
<input type="text" (change)="hero.name=$event.target.value" [ngModel]="hero?name">
```

Similar for textarea:

```
<textarea (change)="dosomething($event.target.value)" [value]="!noHero ? (hero?.name) : ''"></textarea>
<textarea (change)="dosomething($event.target.value)" [ngModel]="!noHero ? (hero?.name) : ''"></textarea>
<textarea (change)="hero.name=$event.target.value" [ngModel]="hero?name"></textarea>
```

Example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbptuy