# Angular2 ngModel binding in the third property level gets undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel

A weird thing is happening on my form or maybe i am not doing it right, let me explain to you by presenting my code.

i have defined a form object inside my component

```
form = {};
```

There is a button on each row with data that when you click it opens a modal widow and also passes the item as argument.

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" (click)="open(item)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
```

This is the method that fires and opens a modal window but also assign the item object to form object above:

```
open = (item: any) => {
    this.inventoryEditModal.open(); //Opens a modal window

    this.form = item; // the assignment 
}
```

The item object is available on the view by printing it out like this:

```
{{ form | json }} // i can see all item properties
```

The modal window contains a form where user will edit the item, so basically the input form fields should get filled with item properties values but for some reason the third level is undefined and i don't understand why, let me show you an screenshot of the second level

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="form.alarmSystem" name="wireless">
```

[image]

The third level gets undefined:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="form.alarmSystem.wireless" name="wireless">
```

[image]

This issue is happening only for the third level "object.object.property". I am only showing one input field but the form contains more than 8 fields they all have same issue.

Not sure what i am missing here, but logically it should work. Do you have see this issue happening here and there or experienced your self?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In fact, the second level is undefined "cannot read property 'wireless of undefined" = alarmSystem is undefined. Have you tried to `console.log(form.alarmSystem)` too?

Comment: Yes i have tried, so basically the whole object is available on the view when i print it out and the alarmSystem as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it helps your case, but I was in a very similar situation.

What helped me out was using the "safe-navigation-operator".

I assume that what you need to do is just add the **?** after *form*:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="form?.alarmSystem.wireless" name="wireless">
```

The docs can be found here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator

Comment: Just FYI, for future reference ... the safe navigation operator cannot be used with an ngModel in the two-way binding.

Comment: How to use this in angular 5

Comment: The ? can't be used in [(ngModel)]

Answer (score 1):

### **There can be 3 possible solutions with Angular 5**

1. Don't assign `ngForm` to the template variable of the form (in form HTML element)

Don't do this -

```
<form #newItem="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveItem(newItem.value);">
```

Instead, do this -

```
    <form (ngSubmit)="saveItem();">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="wireless [(ngModel)]="form.alarmSystem.wireless">
        <submit type="submit">Save</submit>
    </form>
```

> By this, you will be able to assign a 3 level nested property to
> [(ngModel)] without any elvis or safe navigation operator (?).

---

2. If you are assigning `ngForm` to the form template variable then `[(ngModel)]` will give `undefined` for a 3 level nested property even if it already has some value.
   So, use the `name` attribute instead -

   ```
    <form #newItem="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveItem(newItem.value);">
        <input type="text" name="alarmSystem.wireless" ngModel class="form-control">
    </form>
   ```

> Now, in this case, the nested property `alarmSystem.wireless` assigned
> to the `name` attribute will be bound 2-way using `ngModel` directive.
> And you can easily access it in the Event emitter function.

---

3. And the last solution by using elvis operator (?) is -

Here, again we will not assign `ngForm` in the form template variable, although there will not be any error but it won't store the value entered in input correctly.
So, split 2-way data binding with [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) like this

```
<form (ngSubmit)="saveItem();">
    <input type="text" name="wireless" 
                            [ngModel]="form?.alarmSystem?.wireless"
                            (ngModelChange)="form.alarmSystem.wireless=$event" class="form-control">
</form>
```

Also you can refer to this answer - [Correct use of Elvis operator in Angular2 for Dart component's view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161789/correct-use-of-elvis-operator-in-angular2-for-dart-components-view)

> But, I don't recommend this solution as it adds up a lot of code.