# Show nothing if null (JS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have component, where I show data, got from back end.

Here is function for showing data

```
 getData() {
    this.propertyService.getPropertyForEdit(Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'])).subscribe(r => {
        this.property = r;
        this.tabTemplates = [
            { title: this.l('Addresses'), template: this.addressesTemplateRef },
            { title: this.l('Site'), template: this.siteTemplateRef}
        ];
        this.propertiesToDisplay = [
            { displayName: this.l('PropertyTitle'), value: this.property.propertyTitle.name},
            { displayName: this.l('Landlord'), value: this.property.landlord.name},
            { displayName: this.l('Agent'), value: this.property.agent.name },
            { displayName: this.l('BuildingType'), value: this.property.buildingType.name }
        ];
    });
}
```

In this row `value: this.property.landlord.name}` value can be null.

So when it null, I have error

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

How I can fix this?

Comment: `this.property.landlord.name || "N/A"` try doing this

Comment: `this.property.landlord` is undefined. You should check for landlord existing using **fallbacks**. `(this.property && this.property.landlord && this.property.landlord.name) ? this.property.landlord.name : 'N/A'`

Comment: Or use .map and do the same for all undefined values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So when it null, I have error
>
> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

No, it's not `null`, it's `undefined`, which is different.

The error is thrown because `this.property.landlord` is `undefined`. In javascript, trying to access a property (in this case `name`) of `undefined` throws a **TypeError**, by design.

To solve the issue (which is not an issue, but rather a case), you should use **fallbacks** to check whether ancestors of the property exists. In this case, I would handle that in this way:

```
{ displayName: this.l('Landlord'), value: (this.property && this.property.landlord && this.property.landlord.name) ? this.property.landlord.name : 'N/A'},
```

That piece of code specifically:

```
this.property && this.property.landlord && this.property.landlord.name
```

will assert that every ancestor of `name` exists. If any of these doesn't, it will return 'N/A' without throwing any exception.

Comment: @EugeneSukh from your post, I may guess that you're using `angular`. If so, if the variable is directly printed in the html template, you can use the **elvis operator** to avoid the above checks, but it will work **only in angular templates**: `property?.landlord?.name`. If so, you may take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161789/correct-use-of-elvis-operator-in-angular2-for-dart-components-view/35162228

Answer (score 3):

Use a ternary operator:

```
value: (this.property.landlord ? this.property.landlord.name : "defaultValue")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the property landlord is `null(undefined)`.
You can directly handle the `null` check using ternary operators.

`value: (this.property.landlord) ? this.property.landlord.name : null`

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary condition while assigning value. Like this

```
{ displayName: this.l('PropertyTitle'), value: (this.property.propertyTitle.name) ? this.property.propertyTitle.name: null},
```