# Display data in text box, in angular 4 dynamically

Tags: html, angular, angular4-forms

I want to show textbox dynamically when searching an item. The data should be displayed inside the text box. How ever my output only shows the item below the text box.

(I am a fresher if any problem in my question please pardon me)

**Like Below image**

[image][image]

here is my Html code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Item Code</label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Code" required=""/> 
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails;">{{item.ItemCode}}</ng-container>                                                              
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the '1240128' to display inside the textbox? and can it be a list of items?

Comment: @LiefdeWen yes i want to display like inside the text box

Comment: all in a single textbox or comma seperated in the same textbox?

Comment: @LiefdeWen i want to dispaly itemcode inside the text box  then item discription inside another text box etc...

Comment: Then @Shinjo 's answer will work for you

Comment: @LiefdeWen i got an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196857/discussion-between-sreekrishna-and-liefdewen).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `[(ngModel)]` to bind the data.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Item Code</label>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Code" required="" [(ngModel)]="item.ItemCode" />
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: got an error

zone.js:690 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 16 in [item?.ItemCode=$event] in ng:///app/StockOut/StockOut.component.html@38:104 ("                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Code" required="" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="item?.ItemCode" />
                        </ng-container>

Comment: You can use it without `?`. See example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdaqkr. Error explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35162228/11328122

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value to your `input` using the `value` attribute.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails;">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Code" [value]="item.ItemCode" required/>
</ng-container>
```

This will give you a one-way binding for the value (changes in template will not reflect in component).

If you want to bind the values to the component via two-way binding, I suggest you read up on [Template driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) (`ngModel`) and [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) (`formControl`)

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-binding-examples) showing all 3 ways.

Comment: i will try like this but when page loding no text box displaying like the image

Comment: @Sreekrishna check out the working example I have added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-search-filter-kkdyty?file=app/app.component.html)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="search-hero">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off" placeholder="&#61442;  Start searching for a hero by id or name or country">
    </div>
      <li *ngFor="let hero of data | filter:searchText" > 
        {{hero.name}}
      </li>
  </div>
```

.ts

```
searchText;
  data = [
    { id: 11, name: 'CHanaka Nice', country: 'India' },
    { id: 12, name: 'MNarco' , country: 'USA'},

  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use template driven form or reactive form to achieve this.
For template driven form, i just wrote a working code on stackbliz you can open it and check it out.
DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yaiuxn